# Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.executor.impl.RunnableAdapter'

Tags: hazelcast

Im now doing task for create a Simulator of Hazelcast cache system, Im using IExecutorService like this

with this config

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
  executor-service:
    exec:
      pool-size: 32
      queue-capacity: 200
      statistics-enabled: true
```

and doing code like this:

```
    HazelcastInstance myHazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IExecutorService myExecutorService = myHazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("exec");


    @Override
    public void newEntryCacheHandle(DataTransferModel dataTransferModel, boolean flag) {
        res = dataTransferModel;
        log.info("HANDLING ENTRY CACHE");
        myExecutorService.execute(new MyOtherRunnable());
    }


    class MyOtherRunnable implements Runnable, Serializable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.info("MY OTHER RUNNABLE!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
```

this code is for handle entry cache event, but when i have a new event occur this code give me this error log:

```
2023-05-24 14:06:20.723  INFO 4236 --- [g_dirac.event-8] c.e.t.S.CacheEventHandleServiceImpl      : HANDLING ENTRY CACHE
2023-05-24 14:06:20.736  WARN 4236 --- [g_dirac.event-8] c.h.spi.impl.eventservice.EventService   : [172.16.0.2]:5705 [dev] [5.1.5] Error while logging processing event

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.executor.impl.RunnableAdapter'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:129) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:238) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:214) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:199) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:154) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toData(NodeEngineImpl.java:380) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToPartitionOwner(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:253) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceProxy.submit(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:243) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceProxy.execute(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:171) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.example.transferdataservice1.Service.CacheEventHandleServiceImpl.newEntryCacheHandle(CacheEventHandleServiceImpl.java:42) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.newEntryCacheHandle(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.transferdataservice1.Config.HazelcastListenerSubscriberConfiguration.entryAdded(HazelcastListenerSubscriberConfiguration.java:29) ~[main/:na]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapListenerAdaptors.lambda$null$0(MapListenerAdaptors.java:55) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.InternalMapListenerAdapter.onEvent(InternalMapListenerAdapter.java:56) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.InternalMapListenerAdapter.onEvent(InternalMapListenerAdapter.java:35) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.event.MapEventPublishingService.callListener(MapEventPublishingService.java:172) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.event.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEntryEventData(MapEventPublishingService.java:184) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.event.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEvent(MapEventPublishingService.java:83) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.event.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEvent(MapEventPublishingService.java:47) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:128) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:95) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:63) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.RemoteEventProcessor.run(RemoteEventProcessor.java:48) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.process(StripedExecutor.java:245) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:228) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.example.transferdataservice1.Service.CacheEventHandleServiceImpl$MyOtherRunnable'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:129) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:334) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:402) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.RunnableAdapter.writeData(RunnableAdapter.java:78) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:244) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:39) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:235) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.transferdataservice1.Service.CacheEventHandleServiceImpl
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[na:na]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:124) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:117) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:39) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:332) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2023-05-24 14:06:52.840  INFO 4236 --- [g_dirac.event-8] HazelcastListenerSubscriberConfiguration : ALERT, DATA EVICTED TO CACHE EntryEvent{entryEventType=EVICTED, member=Member [172.16.0.2]:5704 - 8a3005cd-bbcd-4181-b00b-847d34567f37, name='data-map', key=data_key_tuanAnh4, oldValue=DataTransferModel(id=1, username=tuanAnh4, data=dataTEST, threadId=null, status=1), value=null, mergingValue=null}
2023-05-24 14:06:52.842  INFO 4236 --- [         task-1] c.e.t.S.CacheEventHandleServiceImpl      : HANDLING EVICT CACHE
2023-05-24 14:11:20.440  INFO 4236 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

so what i need to do now for create a executor of hazelcast.

I was look at this doc: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/computing/executor-service

Thank for reading.

this code is for handle entry cache event

i want it to log a message when entry cache event occur.

Comment: Is `class MyOtherRunnable` nested in another class ... which might not be serializable ? If so, try `static class MyOtherRunnable`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's solve my problem, but i ran into another problem, that if i put MyOtherRunnable class in a static class, i cant run it exactly as i expect. Can you explain that why or what is exactly nested in another class mean, thank you.

Comment: oh Thanks you again, i understand what nested class is. Can i ask you somehow to handle this case? i want it is nested class and dont want to put it in a static class ?